# Table rows does not shows up in Page Source

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, html-table

I'm populating a table in my jquery via Ajax response. I need to click on the rows of the table to populate more information. When I click the row to extract the `row_id`, with the following code:

```
(function(){
    $('#bags_table tr').click(function() {
            alert(1)
          alert($(this).attr('id')); //trying to alert id of the clicked row          

    });
});
```

Upon clicking the row, the alert does not happens. Upon viewing the page source, it shows an empty table.

I'm generating the table like this.

```
function bags_table_func(result){

    var rows = "<tr><th>Seal No.</th><th>Status</th><th>Destination</th><th>Total Packets</th><th>Max. Weight</th>" + 
               "<th>Min. Weight</th><th>Avg. Weight</th><th>Total Weight</th></tr>"

    for (var obj in result){
        if (obj == 'last_bagged_on'){
                continue
        }
        else if (result[obj]['status'] == undefined){
            rows += "<tr><td>No Content</td></tr>"
            break
        }
        rows += "<tr id = '"+obj+"'><td>" + obj+"</td><td>" + result[obj]["status"] + "</td><td>" + 
                    result[obj]["destination"] + "</td><td>" + result[obj]["total_packets"] + "</td><td>" + 
                    result[obj]["max_weight"] + "</td><td>" + result[obj]["min_weight"] + "</td><td>" + 
                    result[obj]["avg_weight"] + "</td><td>" + result[obj]["total_weight"] + "</td><td><a href = '#'>Details</td></tr>"
    }
    $("#bags_table").html(rows);
}
```

How can I make the Ajax Response generated table **clicked?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are generating table via code and for the dynamic you should use [event delegation method](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

```
$(document).on('click','#bags_table tr',function() {
     alert(1)
     alert($(this).attr('id')); //trying to alert id of the clicked row          
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) with [`.on()`](https://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
$(document.body).on('click','#bags_table tr',function () {
   alert(1)
   alert($(this).attr('id')); //trying to alert id of the clicked row          
});
```

Your table rows are appended at runtime, and runtime added elements can't be shown in view source and you can't bind native event to those elements, you need event delegation for the same.

Here in place of `document/document.body` you can have the closest parent element